# R: vector autoregression with penalty for non-cointegrated factors

Tags: r, cointegration, vector-autoregression

I can perform a vector autoregression using the "vars" package in R.

```
library(vars)
data(Canada)
VAR(Canada, p = 2, type = "none")
```

But as I understand it, vector autoregression will only work if the factors used are cointegrated.

Is there an R package for vector autoregression that only selects cointegrated factors, or penalises non-cointegrated factors before the VAR estimation?
I searched http://rseek.org/ but did not find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> vector autoregression will only work if the factors used are cointegrated.

No.

- Vector autoregression (VAR) will work if you have stationary data.
- VAR will work for cointegrated data, too. But using a vector error correction model (VECM) instead of VAR would be a cleaner approach. VECM allows explicitly accounting for the cointegration.
- VAR will not work for integrated but not cointegrated data. (Technically you would be able to run the model, but it would not be a suitable model for the data.)

> Is there an R package for vector autoregression that only selects cointegrated factors, or penalises non cointegrated factors before the var calculation?

I doubt such a package exists in R or another statistical package, because this kind of problem is not that usual, and perhaps little relevant (see the above). Anyhow, you could select the cointegrated factors by hand using e.g. Johansen's test (function `ca.jo` in "urca" package) for cointegration testing.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I will try VECM on cointegrated data.